# Cognito: One account with multiple login names

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to realise a system with AWS Cognito where a user registers an account for one email and later on registers some IoT Device with this account. It should then be possible to login with deviceId and password for the account. So basically i would like to have several login names for the same account.

I was hoping to make this behaviour work with Cognito triggers and the help of a serverside API , but unfortunately there is none.

I would be really grateful for any ideas or pointers. I am new to Cognito so i might be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

While configuring your userpool, in the attributes section, for **How do you want your end users to sign in?** select **Username**.

After this, you can create multiple usernames all pointing to the same email address.

[image]

Comment: Can usernames dynamically be added and removed from the account ?

Comment: You can use presignup lambda triggers. The input data will have email information. And if the email matches the one you are setting up against, then you can set autoconfirmUser as true.

Comment: Can i also check the password of the user ? As far as i know Cognito has no server side API that i can use in Cognito Lambda triggers.

Comment: No passwords are not available to lambda triggers.

Comment: Not related to last comment: Is'nt in the solution you proposed every username a single account just having the same mail ?